# VBA Clear cells in named range that contain specfic character

Tags: vba, excel

All,
I'm am completely unfamiliar w/ VBA, but want to get a code for a fantasy football draft simulation that will "reset" the draft selections.

Parameters: the size of the data is 12 teams (columns), and 18 rounds (rows). The data is not adjacent, so I named the the range that I want to reset "DataVal"

The league is a keeper league which means that there are players already in selected cells prior to the draft, so I don't want those cleared. To differentiate between kept and unkept players, the unkept players have their positions in parentheses.

Request: I want a code that clears all cells containing "**(**" *or if that's not possible, "(RB)" , "(QB)" , "(WR)" , "(TE)" , "(TD)" , "(PK)"* within range "DataVal"  which I can attach to a Button

Comment: Nice. Completely unfamiliar: This means: Press ALT+F11 and start coding! Some great resources are [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/), [Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) and [Ron de Bruin's website](http://www.rondebruin.nl). Documentation on each Class you can find using Google + MSDN. 
I'd say: Start coding and when you run into a specific problem, post your code here and we'll be happy to help out. Until then: Please know that StackOverflow is not a free coding service and we're not going to do your work for you - That would be a paid job for most people.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in a regular module:

```
Sub ClearCells()

Dim rng as Range

With Range("DataVal") 'You had a named range named "DataVal" right?
    For each rng in .cells
        If Left(rng.value, 1) = "(" Then 'All values that start with "("
           rng.ClearContents
        End If
    Next rng
End With
End Sub
```

It loops over each cell in your named range, if the first character in the cell is "(" it'll clear that cell.

Next, add a button and attach the "ClearCells" macro to it.

Still read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your next one though.